# Program to read the full RAM chip

Tags: kernel, memory, c

I am trying to find a clever and simple way to read every address of memory. I am new to kernel development, but I presume this program will need to run in kernel space to have access to the whole memory.

I am sure there is a simple and efficient way. One that I found is this: https://github.com/alwilson/pgscrap/blob/master/pgscrap.c

Bit hacky to my taste, so I was wondering if there was a cleaner approach?

(If it's important to you, the reason for this memory "patrol" is to scrub the whole memory to check for single bit flips before they become uncorrectable. Some memory controllers can do this "patrol" invisibly on the hardware side, but mine will only correct errors when the byte is accessed/read)

Comment: Could you go into more detail regarding what you don’t like about `pgscrap`?

Comment: I find the way to recuperate the `module_first_online_pgdat()` and `module_next_zone()` functions very weird. Also I wonder if there is a more efficient way to actually do the read? Apart from that, it's really the method that I find strange; I would have thought there was a simpler way than to iterate over every zone, and iterate over every frame/page in each zone.